# Adjust set of values within group so they sum to exactly 100

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

The data validation on a software platform insists that each person's allocations must be integers that sum to exactly 100.  Say a person is allocated 33-33-33 across three projects, one of those should be adjusted up to 34 before the submission is accepted. If 25-76, one of those should be adjusted down by 1.  It does not matter which is adjusted.

Here's sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(person = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                  proj = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "e"),
                  alloc = c(40, 50, 11, 33, 33, 33))

dat
  person proj alloc
1      1    a    40
2      1    b    50
3      1    c    11
4      2    a    33
5      2    d    33
6      2    e    33
```

Correct adjusted values of `dat$alloc` in this example would include `39, 50, 11, 34, 33, 33` or `40, 50, 10, 33, 33, 34` etc.

What's a clean, simple way to do this?  Right now I'm creating a new data.frame to calculate adjustments, then joining it back in using a dummy row ID variable, etc.  I'd prefer to do it just within a dplyr `group_by` operation and avoid creating a separate data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace one of the values with the difference between 100 and the sum of the other values, for example

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(alloc=c(100-sum(alloc[-1]), alloc[-1]))
```

Here we replace the first value `alloc[1]` with `100-sum(alloc[-1])` and keep all the other values.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation which assigns the rounding to the largest number:

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  arrange(person, -alloc, proj)) %>%
  mutate(alloc = alloc + if_else(row_number() == 1, 100 - sum(alloc), 0))
```